# read array from plist and only return item if match was found

Tags: ios, swift, plist, nssortdescriptor

i'm trying to work my way through a plist...
Now i wanted to only fetch item 1 if it was a genre of Soft how do i achieve this ?

i'm trying to sort my way through it but it doesn't work...

```
 var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("radioChannels", ofType: "plist")
    self.menuItemArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as NSMutableArray!
    for obj: AnyObject in menuItemArray {
        if let dict = obj as? NSDictionary {
            if let menuPunkt = dict["genre"] as? String {
                if menuPunkt as String == ("Soft"){
                    println("Soft \(menuPunkt)")
                }
            } else {
                println("failed with menuPunkt")
            }
        } else {
            println("failed to convert to NSDictionary")
        }
    }
```

this i only tried but doest work

```
    var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Soft", ascending: true)
    self.sortedResults = menuItemArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```

[image: Plist]

Comment: The loop at the top is essentially what you're looking for (although I'd use filter and eliminate a lot of code.  I'm not sure what the sorting below it is supposed to accomplish or how it relates to your question.  It's also not particularly clear exactly what your question is.  What isn't happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: David i want to only fetch the from the plist if there is a genre called soft, then load that into a array and display it it in a uicollectionview

Comment: Do you want to find genre in this plist?

Comment: yes and if the genre has a string of Soft then load it into a array, not just the soft but the entire item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use the filter built-in.  The following snippet will give you an array of items with a genre of "soft":

```
if let menuItemArray = menuItemArray as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    var softItems = menuItemArray.filter({
        if let genre = $0["genre"] as? String {
            return genre.lowercaseString == "soft"
        }
        return false
    })
    println("\(softItems)")
}
```

I prefer this solution over the NSPredicate solution for a couple of reasons, first, once you typecast the NSMutableArray into a swift array of the appropriate type, it's pretty much pure swift, and second, `NSPredicate` is a pretty heavy Objective-C bat for a really simple problem.

Also note that the typecast/check should really be done one-time when the plist is loaded rather than doing it each time you build your view contents, it's really only included in the snippet for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use NSPredicate for filtering genre?

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "genre = 'soft'")!
 let filteredArray = self.menuItems.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also give this code a try!

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("radioChannels", ofType: "plist") {
            if let myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
                for dict in myArray {
                    if let genre = dict["genre"] as? String{

                        if genre == "genre1"  {
                            print("genre1")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```